# How to debug *.ashx file which is on server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, remote-debugging, ashx

i've got *.ashx file on the server which is a help service for my applications. I try to debug this file localy from Visual Studio. I set the breakpoints and then i attach to proces w3wp.exe which is running on the server but after visual studio attach then breakpoint becomes empty(The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document). Did someone knows how to debug *.ashx file?